# Make Android app undeletable

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [uninstallable app for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415304/uninstallable-app-for-android)

I need to install an Android app on a number of phones - the phones are only for using this app, so the user should not be able to uninstall it.

Have you got an idea how to block uninstalling the app?

I thought that creating an own system image would work, so that even when the user resets the phone the app would still be there (although that's not required; not having the "uninstall" option is enough) - but I also hoped there would be an easier way?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to force users not to uninstall, rather than just telling them not to? I'm assuming this is for some business or something and isn't to be installed on regular strangers phones right?

Comment: Oh! I don't want to install an app which I can't uninstall

Comment: i pretty sure that creating an own system image is the only way

Comment: The phones and hopefully tablets will be handed to people in a bar for use (internet surfing) within the bar. The bar's own app should not be uninstalled.

Comment: It is, thanks for pointing out. I couldn't find it before.

Answer (score 2):

To effectifly do this you need to

- make your own ROM that has the APK in-build
- Lock the bootloader on the phones so they can't install another ROM
- Be better at above then everyone else (because they do tend to get hacked), or make your target audience small enough that nobody bothers to do it (not real safe though).

I'm rather thinking it's not worth the effort, and you might be looking for the wrong solution of your base problem