# How to prevent uninstallation even after a factory reset

Tags: android

I have made a security app, and I want to make it more secure. Are there any means by which I can prevent uninstallation from the device, even by a factory reset?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but it will almost certainly require root privileges.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6415383/830267) should guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I know to do that is converting you app to a System App (just like those ones that come in your phone from factory). Although you will need to make root on your phone for this. With your rooted phone, install Link2SD app and convert your app to a System App.

Answer (score -1):

That will only be possible on a customized Android System.

Comment: customized Android System what dose it means

Comment: That means that you have to download the android os sources, make your changes, build an OS image, and install that image as your operating system on that device!